# Applying CSS to Datatables that has NEXT Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables-1.10

I have this Script that works and does what I need, but it will only apply to the first 10 rows, not to the next page.
My Table id is "MyTable" Here is my JavaScript:

```
                $(document).ready(function()
                            {
                                $(function() 
                                    {
                                      $("#MyTable td").each(function() 
                                      {
                                        if ($(this).text() == 'Pending') 
                                            {
                                              $(this).css('background-color', 
                '#F3E498');
                                            }
                                        if ($(this).text() == 'Approved') 
                                            {
                                              $(this).css('background-color', 
                '#C5F97E');
                                            }
                                        if ($(this).text() == 'Denied') 
                                            {
                                              $(this).css('background-color', 
                '#FF5733');
                                            }
                                        
                                      });
                                    });
                            });
```

So needless to say I am kida stuck here where at row 11th, my script quits working through next pages, I would appreciate any suggestions.
[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I1I7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only rows that are visible in the datatable are actually in the DOM. Therefore you could either call your $.each loop each time the page changes or (I think better) use https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow or https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell

Here's a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dhqcekm9/

**CSS**

```
.approved {
  background-color: #C5F97E;
}

.denied {
  background-color: #FF5733;
}

.pending {
  background-color: #F3E498;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Denied</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Denied</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Denied</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#table').dataTable({
  'columnDefs': [{
    'targets': 1,
    'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      switch (cellData) {
        case 'Approved':
          $(td).addClass('approved');
          break;
        case 'Denied':
          $(td).addClass('denied');
          break;
        case 'Pending':
          $(td).addClass('pending');
          break;
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

[image: JSFiddle Datatable page 2]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I tried both, none worked, they won't even apply color unless I am doing something wrong ? I created a css class for "approved"here is my code $('#MyTable').dataTable( {
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
   if ( data[7] == 'Approved' ) {
     $(row).addClass( 'approved' );
   }
    }
  });

Comment: The cell doesn't work either :
$(document).ready(function()
   $('#MyTable').dataTable( 
   {
      "columnDefs": [ 
      {
     "targets": -1,
     "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) 
     {
       if ( cellData == 'Approved' ) 
        {
       $(td).css('color', 'red')
        }
     }
      }
      ]
   });
  });

Comment: Assuming column 7 is the one you want and your stylesheet has the .approved class defined, you need to apply the class to the TD not the row i.e. ```$(row).find('td').addClass( 'approved' );```

Comment: Just added a JSFiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you @Adey_888, It won't work I have 8 columns, so the last one is #7 which contains Status.. but even then I am intersted in Cell color not the entire Row, may I use CreatedCell instead ?$('#MyTable').dataTable({
       "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex) 
     {
      switch (data[7]) {
      case "Approved":
        $(row).find('td').addClass('approved');
        break;
      case "Denied":
        $(row).find('td').addClass('denied');
        break;
      case "Pending":
        $(row).find('td').addClass('pending');
        break;
      }
       }
     });

Comment: Answer updated: https://jsfiddle.net/dhqcekm9/

Comment: @Adey-888
Thank you so much again, it's not working at all, the only one that works actually is the initial one, but just not applying to other pages ..is there a way to modify it at all ?

Comment: Is there JSFiddle working for you? As you can see in the picture I just added to the answer, it is working there for me across both pages. Perhaps fork the JS Fiddle and add some of your own code then I can help debug that later today.

Comment: Yes I know I can see yours working fine on JsFiddle, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong, is it maybe because my CSS and JS are not inline ? but again, my initial Script works fine !!
I will see if I can create a Fiddle for you.
Much appreciated.

Comment: Here is my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/alachgar/5083aoLm/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rf5b84s9/1/ There were two things that needed addressing: 1) "'targets': 2" needed to be "'targets': 1" for the correct column. 2) The CSS formatting of the approved/pending/denied classes was being overridden by Bootstrap classes. For these to take precedence they need to be included after the Bootstrap CSS (which they were) and include the "!important" property to ensure they are applied.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rf5b84s9/2/ just had to make an additional "!important" on the hover class to make sure that is applied over the top!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rf5b84s9/3/ to put the datatables initialisation in the $(document).ready() function. Doesn't seem to change anything on the JSFiddle, but the datatables initialisation would've been called twice as it was.

Comment: Thank you a bunch adey_888, i troublesooted the issue, it was because I was using a <center> tag on my td like:<td><center><?php echo $comp['status']?></center></td>
So the moment I changed it it all started workin :-) Weird Hen ?:-) 
Anyway Thanks a lot, keep the good work up.

Comment: No worries at all. Happy to help. Datatables is awesome. Feel free to make my answer as accepted :)